# Using javascript to evoke an event on Facebook.com

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Facebook has a TextArea on top of every group page that allows users to post a message to the group, I have created a chrome extension that successfully adds text to that TextArea.

This extension will be used by my company to reduce work times on specific tasks.

On cases when the message contains a link, Facebook automatically adds a preview box that has metadata of the submitted URL, this does not occur when the TextArea is changed via $().value = "my text";

I have been trying to evoke this behavior and force it to create the link for my message using the chrome console / extension in many ways, the only thing that triggers it is actually typing in the TextArea (not using the code / chrome extension)

Using console / chrome extension, the value of the TextArea can be changed with this:

```
document.getElementsByName("xhpc_message_text")[0].focus();
document.getElementsByName("xhpc_message_text")[0].value = "I love www.stackoverflow.com";
document.getElementsByName("xhpc_message")[0].value      = "I love www.stackoverflow.com";
```

[image: textarea]

Would appreciate any help in simulating a real keypress that invokes the link preview or even directly invoking the link preview to achieve this behavior.

Comment: not sure if i understand correctly: do you want to prefill the message? because that´s surely not allowed.

Comment: It's for personal use in-house script

Comment: Have you tried to trigger `keyup` on the element after updating?

Comment: Tried to do that in many ways including:
document.getElementsByName("xhpc_message_text")[0].keyup();
TypeError: undefined is not a function

any other way you know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HTMLElement`s don't have a `keyup` method. To trigger events programmatically, you'll have to use `EventTarget.dispatchEvent`. Since all `HTMLElement`s are instances of `EventTarget` (`HTMLElement.prototype instanceof EventTarget`), you can do:

```
var keydown = new Event('keydown');
document.querySelector('[name=xhpc_message_text]').dispatchEvent(keydown);
```

Also note that Facebook previews a link only if it has more characters after the link.

```
var messageBox = document.querySelector('[name=xhpc_message_text]');
messageBox.dispatchEvent(new Event('focus'));
messageBox.value = 'www.stackoverflow.com ';
messageBox.dispatchEvent(new Event('keydown'));
```

Comment: Thanks, This does actually fire the event on the text-area. however the text is not being typed into the text-box probably thus not creating the link attachment, any clue why?

Comment: After actually firing the event on the text-area Facebook did not create the link attachment, Facebook is not using event handlers here? so how come when a space is manually typed the preview is invoked?

Comment: These are event listeners for the Textarea, I tried firing them all without any success: http://i.imgur.com/Eu7dPaq.png

Comment: Thanks this has been solved using using the Paste event.